# Extract and Set portions of an array in CUDA

Tags: cuda, memcpy

I have to extract sections of an array and set the chunk to another array.

For instance, I have a 2d array (in 1d format) like A[32 X 32]; there is another array B[64 X 64] and I would want to copy an 8X8 chunk of B, starting from (0,8) of B and place it in (8,8) of A.

At present, I would probably use something like the kernel below, for getting a portion of data when offsets are passed. A similar one could also be used to setting chunks to a larger array.

```
__global__ void get_chunk (double *data, double *sub, int xstart, int ystart, int rows, int cols, int subset)
 {
    int i,j;
    i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    for (j = 0; j < subset; j++)
            sub[i*subset+j] = data[i*cols + (xstart*cols + ystart)+j];

 }
```

I think the same could be done using a variant of cudamemCpy* (perhaps cudamemCpyArray(...)), but I am not sure how to do it. I need some code samples, or some directions on how it could be done.

PS I had the exact same question in nvidia forums, got no reply so trying here. http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=223386

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for a kernel if you just want to copy data from one array to another on the device.

If you have your device pointers with your source data and your allocated target pointer in host code:

**Pseudocode:**

```
//source and target device pointers
double * source_d, target_d;

//get offseted source pointer
double * offTarget_d + offset * sizeof(double);

//copy n elements from offseted source data to target device pointer
cudaMemcpy(offTarget_d, source_d, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);
```

*It was not clear if you just want to copy a range of a 1D array or if you want to copy a range of each row in a 2D array into the target row of another 2D array*

Comment: @djmj: a for loop is actually a good idea, but just not one with a unit stride. Multiple copies per thread will be more efficient than just one - it helps hide thread scheduling overheads and setup costs.

Comment: True, but what is the performance cost of thread scheduling?, Most sources state that the gpu should be kept busy using as much threads as possible while having 100% occupancy. (I assumed a simple 1D array copy kernel). Memory latency is here a bigger problem which can be hidden using 100% occupancy. See performance charts: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~volkov/volkov10-GTC.pdf#page=30

Comment: @djmj: I am not sure I follow. The performance charts you linked to completely contradict what you wrote in your comment. They show that the highest memcpy bandwidth is achieved by using fewer threads and more parallel work per thread. The highest performance reached is at _4%_ occupancy, not 100%......

Comment: Yes you are right my 100% statement was not correct, even the benefit seems to be very small at the given example (and wanna see unrolled version!). I just wanted to point it out that memory latency will be more important here and I assume that an dynamic large loop will execute slower then a small unrolled one. On my last edit i removed that unroll statement from my previous comment somehow.

Comment: The original question was about copying 2D subsets of 2D arrays.  That would require a bunch of disjoint `cudaMemcpy` calls which would be inefficient.  If you have a lot of small 2D chunks to copy, I would recommend writing a kernel and having a warp-sized group of threads perform each copy independently.